# How to add ads in exoplayer playlist

Tags: android, kotlin, ads, adsense, exoplayer

I want to add ads from google adsense in my exoplayer playlist. I was able to create the playlist in exoplayer using concatenating media source now i want to insert ads in the playlist in certain intervals.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very desired feature that unfortunately has not been added yet. See the open issue [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3750)